# Converting Ant module to Maven, what is the best practices?

Tags: java, maven, ant

Many tools and ways are used to convert from ant to maven but what was the best for this migration ?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though, these may not be enough, but I've compiled some common practices while transferring module from ant to maven.

1. Delete your `build.xml` completely. You'd have to rewrite it again because maven doesn't use it at all.
2. Introduce a new `pom.xml`.
3. Define main class in `<mainClass>src.com.test.Main</mainClass>` using `maven-compiler-plugin`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29920434/2815219) answer.
4. For .jar that you're using in your `build.xml` search their dependencies online and add then in pom.xml. You can also add [local dependencies in your pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13160960/2815219).
5. Transfer your images, text, audio, video, docs, pdf, xml to resources folder. (see also: [What is the purpose for the resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25786667/2815219))

For more best practices see this answer also.
[Moving onto Maven Anyway...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17239578/2815219)